# ADO and Stored procedure call

Tags: excel, vba, adodb

I am using the code below but my recordset is not open, What am I doing wrong?

```
Dim rs As New ADODB.RecordSet
Dim Conn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command

Sql = "[dbo].[lc_PM11132_JCCostCashFlow_Report] ?"
With cmd
.ActiveConnection = Conn
.CommandText = Sql
.Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@ReportType", adInteger, adParamInput)
.Parameters("@ReportType") = 1
End With
rs.Open cmd
rs.MoveFirst
```

Comment: Have you opened the `Connection` anywhere?

Comment: YEs the connection works